# Hide Audiorecord option on HTML5's input file control

Tags: html, mobile

I'm trying to play music or video by using html5's input control of type `file` in mobile:

```
<input id="videomusic" type="file" accept="audio/*,video/*"/>
```

When I use this code, a prompt is presented with the following options:

1. **AudioRecord**
2. **Documents**

> I just need the **Documents** option, **How can I hide/remove the other?**

Answer (score 0):

This isn't your choice.  It's up to the browser to decide what it wants to do.

You'll find that the behavior varies from device to device.  Generally speaking, if you didn't specify `accept`, they'll get just a file browser rather than the option to record some media to then upload.  But, you might consider leaving what you have and letting the user and their browser do what they choose.

Comment: You are right, right now I am using ionic 2 (angular 2) maybe I should try a plugin instead, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @KaroA No, there's nothing you can do about this short of a native app.  This is browser functionality, not something in your web application.